# ffmpy.FFExecutableNotFoundError: Executable 'ffmpeg' not found?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have been trying to get rid of this error for a long time by installing (pip, PATH variable) but nothing... Help?

My code:

```html
import ffmpy
ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={path+'/Stage1Rap.wav': None}, outputs={path+'/FinalRap.mp3': ["-filter:a", "atempo=0.5"]})
ff.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass executable parameter with the path of ffmpeg executable file in ffmpy.FFmpeg().
So find the executable file of ffmpeg in your system and pass it.

```
import ffmpy

ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(executable='C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', inputs={path+'/Stage1Rap.wav': None}, outputs={path+'/FinalRap.mp3': ["-filter:a", "atempo=0.5"]})
ff.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ffmpeg executables. You have to download the FFmpeg from ffmpeg.org and give the path as described by j suman

Answer (score 0):

Install ffmpeg executable and keep it on path & should work. If its not on path then you might want to give executable path.